# Django: Generic views based 'as_view()' method

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.7

I was working on an application wherein I created a generic `ListView`. Now, while defining that view in my `urls.py`, I read from the documentation that I need to use the `as_view()` method as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .views import BlogIndex

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', BlogIndex.as_view(), name="index"),
)
```

Now, I didn't really understood what the documentation had to say about this method. Can someone shed some light into this concept?

Comment: Your question is not clear. `as_view()` is what you have to call to link a class-based view into your URL. What are you asking about?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I guess you just answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In class-based views, you have to call `as_view()` function so as to return a **callable view** that takes a `request` and returns a `response.` **It's the main entry-point in request-response cycle in case of generic views.**

**`as_view` is the function(class method) which will connect my `MyView` class with it's url.**

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view):

> classmethod as_view(**initkwargs)
> Returns a callable view that takes a request and returns a response:

You just can't use class-based views like you could in normal function-based views.

```
BlogIndex(request) # can't do this in case of CBVs
```

The above code is not valid if you want the CBVs to function properly. For that, you need to provide a view which is callable and then pass request to it. For example:

```
response = MyView.as_view()(request)  # valid way
```

By calling the `as_view()` function on my view class `MyView` will give me a view which I will call with `request` parameter to initiate the request-response cycle.

**In your case:**

```
my_callable_view = BlogIndex.as_view() # returns a callable view
<function blog.views.BlogIndex>
```

Now, call this function and pass the `request`.

```
 response = my_callable_view(request) # generate proper response
```

Answer (score 3):

view function have different format than before because :

> 1. This view will actually be implemented as a class
> 2. We will be inheriting from an existing generic view function that already does most of what we want this view function to do, rather
>      than writing our own from scratch.
> 3. Class method  as_view()- this does all the work of creating an instance of the class, and making sure that the right handler methods
>      are called for incoming HTTP requests.

ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can try to write the as_view with pseudo-code:

```
class ViewClass():
      #other stuff
      def as_view(self):
           return self.render(*args)
```

It return the render function inside the CBV.
So it actually is the same as path('some_path',views.some_view_function,name='some_name')
Of course, there there is actually much more things going on than only render function, for example to verify and save the content inside post queryDict, actually you need `def post():` to handle the post, in function you just `if request.method == 'POST'` they are actually mutual.
To be specific, as_view() just generate a overall function, including  `if request.method =='POST': #some code` Maybe the actual code doesn't work like that, but you could understand it this way if you are not prepared to contribute to django source code yourself.