# In Django urls, when is it required to use the as_view() method when calling views?

Tags: python, django

For my registration app, I am using the Django's LoginView method to let users log in. My urls.py for this app looks like this:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as views_stock
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/login/', views_stock.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', views_stock.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='logout'),
    path('accounts/register', views.register, name='register')
]
```

I added as_view(), as recommended on the documentation. But for my own view, 'register', I did not include as_view(). Is it better practice to include it for 'register' as well or is it not needed?

Comment: please find answer below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/31491074/6871676

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make use of a [*class-based view* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/#class-based-views). The [**`LoginView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) and [**`LogoutView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView) are *classes*.

Such class-based views are classes that inherit from the [**`View`** class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View) (for example a `TemplateView` is a subclass of `View`), and the `View` class offers a [`.as_view(…)` method method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view).

This method will export a function that will take a `request` and positional and named parameters, just like a function-based view does. For function-based views, so a simply function, you can not use `.as_view(…)`, since such functions have no `.as_view` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You only use the `as_view()` function when your view is [class-based](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/).

For simpler views only defined as functions you only include it as is (thus omitting the `as_view()`).