# Django call DRF endpoint in another view and pass data into html template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a Django REST Framework endpoint that returns all the data I need for my page. I am trying to call this endpoint in one of my views and pass the response to the html template as part of the render.

when I `print(response)` it returns `<function SetsIndividualData at 0x00000201656AB9D8>`. All nothing is returned when I use `{{ response.name }}` in the html template. What am I missing here?

**urls.py**

```py
path('sets/<str:setCode>/', setsIndividualPage),
path('sets/<str:setCode>/sets-individual-data/', SetsIndividualData.as_view(), name='sets-individual-data'),
```

**views.py**

```py
def setsIndividualPage(request, setCode):
    response = SetsIndividualData.as_view()
    print(response)
    return render(request, "magic/sets-individual.html", {'response': response})

class SetsIndividualData(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SetSerializers

    def get_queryset(self):
        SQL_EXPRESSION = "CAST((REGEXP_MATCH(number, '\d+'))[1] as INTEGER)"
        setCode = self.kwargs.get('setCode', None)
        queryList = Set.objects.filter(code=setCode.upper()).prefetch_related(Prefetch('cards', queryset=Card.objects.extra(select={'int': SQL_EXPRESSION}).order_by('int', 'number')))
        return queryList
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31491074/11282077

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
response = SetsIndividualData.as_view()(request)
print(response)
```